# Get object from object attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question may be dumb but I was wondering if getting the object instance from an attribute of this instance was feasible ?

Example :

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

person = Person(age=2)
```

And now I would like to get `person` from `person.age`, like :

```
person_instance = get_object_instance(person.age)
```

My example here is really simple and, sure, I can access it directly like this `person_instance = person` but in my code it is way more complex than that as I am passing `person.age` as a parameter to a complex function.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Comment: Is there anything preventing you to pass the whole object to your function and then access the age field?

Comment: @kristaps Not possible

Comment: Could give more details on the constraints making it impossible?